How to estimate autocorrelation of a signal in AWGN
I have a data sequence of a signal in AWGN
$$y(n)=\begin{cases}x(n)+w(n)&n=n_0,...,n_{L-1}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
for $n=0,...,N-1$, where $L\leq{N}$ and $w(n)$ is a white gaussian noise of zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. I do FFT of y(n) and get $Y(k)=X(k)+W(k)$ where $Y(k)$, $X(k)$ and $W(k)$ are FFTs of $y(n)$, $x(n)$ and $w(n)$ respectively. Then I want to make a biased estimate of the autocorrelation of $X(k)$ by
$$\hat{R}_{XX}(m)=\begin{cases}\sum_{k=0}^{N-m-1}Y_{k+m}Y_k^*&m\geq0\\\hat{R}_{XX}^{*}(-m)&m<0,\end{cases}$$
where ${}^*$ stands for complex conjugate. $NL\sigma^2$ should be subtracted from $\hat{R}_{XX}(0)$. How about the other taps?

Assuming it is pure white noise, you only need to adjust the zero-lag coefficient. However, white noise is a mathematical construct.

I did some monte carlo simulation with white noise only. There are clearly  nonzero values in the other taps.

White noise is uncorrelated in time, and therefore its autocorrelation will be $N\sigma^2\delta[m]$, where $N$ is the signal length, $\sigma$ is the noise variance, $\delta$ is the discrete-time unit impulse function, and $m$ is the lag. As such, theoretically you will only need a correction at zero lag ($m=0$). However, be aware that it is impossible to generate a finite signal that will have such an autocorrelation. At best, all that can be done is showing that the aforementioned function is the expected value by averaging many simulations. In contrast, a random Gaussian white noise signal can easily be generated that will have a circular autocorrelation that is described by $N\sigma^2\delta[m\text{ mod }N]$.
Here is some simple example Matlab code that demonstrates these:
% identify expected value by averaging multiple lots of simulations
n = 50;
cum_auto = zeros(2*n-1,1);
for k = 1:20000
    noise = randn(n,1);
    cum_auto = cum_auto + xcorr(noise);
    if (k == 1)
        [initial, lags] = xcorr(noise);
    end
end

% display one autocorrelation versus average of many
figure;
plot(lags,[initial,cum_auto/k]); xlabel('lag');
ylabel('autocorrelation')
legend({'one iteration',sprintf('average of %dk iterations',k/1000)})
grid on

% generate a random gaussian white noise sequence
freq = (0:n-1)/n;
fft_noise = fft(noise);
fft_noise_white = sqrt(sum(abs(fft_noise(2:end)).^2)/(n-1)).*exp(1i*angle(fft_noise));
circ_auto = ifft(fft_noise_white.*conj(fft_noise_white));
noise_white = ifft(fft_noise_white,'symmetric');

% display circular autocorrelation result
figure;
var_noise = var(noise,1);
subplot(2,2,1); plot(abs(fft_noise_white)); title('noise frequency domain'); ylim([0,max(abs(fft_noise_white))*1.1]); xlabel('frequency (cycles/sample)')
subplot(2,2,3); plot(noise_white); title('noise time domain'); xlabel('sample')
subplot(2,2,2); histogram(noise_white); title('noise distribution')
subplot(2,2,4); plot(0:n-1,circ_auto); xlim([-10,n-1+10]); ylim(n*var_noise*[-0.1, 1.1])
xlabel('lag'); title('circular autocorrelation')

Here is the first figure that shows the average autocorrelation converging towards the expected value:

Here is the second figure that demonstrates the perfect circular autocorrelation result for white noise:

Therefore, the best you can do is subtract the random gaussian white noise autocorrelation expected value. This, of course, assumes that $w[n]$ does not correlate with $x[n]$.

Thank you very much. But in my question there may be less nonzero taps than the length of data sequence in the time domain. And I want to estimate the autocorrelation in the frequency domain. You may find large nonzero autocorrelation values if the number of nonzero taps in the time domain is small.

Ok, my understanding is now that you are padding (appending) your time domain signal with $N-L$ zeros, and that you want to compute the frequency domain autocorrelation rather than using the frequency domain to compute the time domain autocorrelation. Is that correct?

It's not padding. It's just some discrete  taps in time domain are zero. And I want to compute frequency domain autocorrelation.

So, you want to zero random elements of your signal (which I presume is due to those elements corresponding to missing values, such as an intermittently faulty sensor)? If so, because the setting of zeros is random, the frequency domain autocorrelation expected value is $N(\mu^2+\sigma^2)\delta[m]$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the noise signal mean and variance, respectively, after the random zeroing. I confirmed this result with a slight modification to my above Matlab code that randomly zeroed a random number of elements in a random noise signal.

You're using matlab. Then please try this code: n = 50;
cum_auto = zeros(2*n-1,1);
for k = 1:20000
noise = zeros(n,1); noise([2,8,10])=complex(randn(3,1),randn(3,1)); noise=fft(noise);
cum_auto = cum_auto + xcorr(noise); end

Ok, in that case the elements that are zero remain fixed. What is the application? This seems to be quite a niche. You might find a solution by searching terms relevant to the field on https://scholar.google.com/

It's just small noise like taps are removed before taking fft. I'm not sure what to search for.

Indeed, if this has no real-world application, no purpose, then it probably will make it harder to find others who have worked on this problem.

It's ofdm thing. So there's transform from time to frequency. I'll try some search. Thank you very much.
